# The sum of n independent poisson($\lambda_i$) random variables is poisson($\sum_1^n \lambda_i$) random variable.

Tags: probability-theory

How can I show that the sum of n independet poisson random variables is a poisson random variable? I need to conclude that the sum of i.r.v with distribution $Poisson(\lambda_i)$, i=1,...,n, is $Poisson(\sum_1^n \lambda_i)$.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Independent_Poisson_Random_Variables_is_Poisson

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580284/how-to-show-that-the-sum-of-two-poisson-random-variables-is-a-poisson-random-var

Comment: Also [Poisson Distribution of sum of two random independent variables X, Y](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/221078)