# Explicit form in a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

What is $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le c \,\middle|\, \lambda = \lambda_0 \right) $ when $X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$?

Is it right to say $X_1+\dots+X_n\sim\text{Poisson}(n\lambda_0)$ then $\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le c \,\middle|\, \lambda = \lambda_0 \right)=\sum_{k=1}^cn^k\lambda_0^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda_0}}{k!}$?

Comment: The $X_i$ need to be [conditionally] independent [given $\lambda = \lambda_0$].

Comment: @angryavian Could you explain further? I took $\lambda=\lambda_0$ to mean $X_i=\sum \lambda_0^k\frac{e^{-\lambda_0}}{k!}$.

Comment: If $X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_0)$ are **independent**, then $X_1 + \cdots + X_n \sim \text{Poisson}(n \lambda_0)$. Also your comment does not make sense; did you try to write the CDF of $X_i$?

Comment: @angryavian Yes,isn't it the CDF? I was considering the accepted answer for that question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y  If $\mu=\lambda=\lambda_0$ then $\text{Pr}(X_1+X_2=c)=\frac{(2\lambda_0)^c}{c!}e^{-2\lambda_0}$.  In my case $\text{Pr}(X_1+\dots+X_n=c|\lambda=\lambda_0)=\frac{(n\lambda_0)^c}{c!}e^{-n\lambda_0}$ then $\text{Pr}(X_1+\dots+X_n\leq c|\lambda=\lambda_0)=\sum_{k=1}^c\frac{(n\lambda_0)^k}{k!}e^{-n\lambda_0}$.

Comment: The point of my comments is to emphasize that you need an **independence** assumption (which you have not explicitly mentioned) in order to use that result. But if you do have independence, then what you have written in your original question is fine.

Comment: What is this conditioning on the parameter $\lambda$? Is $\lambda$ a RV too in this example?