# is the sum of two poisson distribution independent from the others variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

so i have this question to answer

```
Assuming that ξ1 and ξ2 are two independent Poisson random variables with 
parameters, respectively, λ1>0 and λ2>0, lets define ξ3 as equal to ξ1+ξ2.
are ξ3  and ξ1 independent ? justify it.
```

since ξ3 follows a poisson distribution with parameter λ1+λ2 it should be indepedent right ? 
but i'm not sure and i'd like to know if anyone can help me prove it or tell me if it's false

Comment: Hint: if $\xi_1 > 0$, can $\xi_3 = 0$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Poisson Distribution of sum of two random independent variables $X$, $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ξ1 and  ξ3 are not independent. 
Proof: let's consider that ξ1 and ξ3 are independent. Then cov(ξ1,ξ3)=0 => cov(ξ1, ξ1+ ξ2) = 0 => cov(ξ1,ξ1) +  cov(ξ1,ξ2) = 0. But we know that ξ1 and ξ2 are independent so  cov(ξ1,ξ2) = 0 and what we get is: cov(ξ1,ξ1) = 0 => var(ξ1) = 0 which doesn't hold because var(ξ1) = λ1 > 0.

Comment: Would it not be easier to write $\text{cov}(ξ1,ξ3)= \text{cov}(\xi_1, \xi_1+ \xi_2) = \text{cov}(\xi_1,\xi_1) +\text{cov}(\xi_1,\xi_2) = \lambda_1>0$ or something similar, and avoid the need for a contradiction?