# Given $X_i$ takes a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, what it the distribution of a sum of $n$ of these independent $X_i$?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

My thoughts are that $X$ itself would follow a Poisson distribution?

Comment: What brought you to think that?

Comment: A google search gives https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y.