# normal approximation about three poisson distributions

Tags: probability

The number of items handed in to the Lost Property Office of a busy railway station each day is a $Poi(16)$ random variable on a weekday (Monday to Friday), a $Poi(22)$ random variable on a Saturday and a $Poi(11)$ random variable on a Sunday. The numbers of items handed in to the office on different days are independent.

Use a Normal approximation to find the approximate probability that no more than $100$ items in total are handed in to this Lost Property Office next week (Sunday to Saturday, inclusive).

**About the question above, is there any methods to get the normal approximation by three distributions?**

Comment: If $X$ is the number of items handed into the lost property office in a given week, then $X\sim \text{Poisson}(113)$ which is approximately $\mathcal{N}(113,113)$

Comment: Can you explain a little about why the parameter would be $16\times 5+22+11$? Is there any theorem to get it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y