# (Poisson distribution) Probability of X events in a bigger time interval

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

"The number of events in a month is distributed as a Poisson random variable with mean 2. What is the probability that there are 30 events in a year?" (Treat months as equal length)

I have the above question in a text book, so X~Poi(2). And I need to find out P(12X=30) ?
The answer says that Y ~ Poi(24), (I'm guessing Y=12X) but it doesn't say why.

Could someone please explain or prove this result (regarding Y) to me?

Comment: Why would you look at $12X$?  You aren't assured of replicating a single month $12$ times.  As to the official answer, that's how Poisson works.  It scales with time...so it stays Poisson as you change the time window and the average scales as you'd think it would.

Comment: The problem does not say anything about different months being independent, so, $Y=12X$ is a possibility if we do not have independence (but that would change the answer since $P[12X=2]=0$). Most likely you are supposed to assume independence and use the fact that the sum of mutually independent Poisson variables is again Poisson.

Comment: If $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu)$ then - if $X$ and $Y$ are independent - $X+Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$. Exploit this nice property.

Comment: @drhab Thanks I understand the answer now using this property. Is there a proof for it?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221078/75923) for instance.