# Sum of two independent Skellam distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

The distribution of the sum of two (or more) independent Poisson distributed random variables is again a Poisson distribution ([Poisson Distribution of sum of two random independent variables $X$, $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y)).

The distribution of the difference of two independent Poisson distributed random variables is also an analytically known distribution, the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).

Is there also an analytical result for the distribution corresponding to the sum of two (or more) independent Skellam distributed random variables?

Comment: Characteristic functions immediately yield that the finite sums of independent Skellam-distributed rvs are Skellam distributed

Comment: @Snoop uo, sweet! I'd be happy to accept a fleshed out version of this comment as an answer.

Comment: I typed it up. Do let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @Snoop that's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be independent Skellam-distributed rvs with respective parameters $\mu_{1},\mu_2$ and $\nu_1,\nu_2$. Then by independence we have

$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi (X+Y)}]&=E[e^{i\xi  X}]E[e^{i\xi Y}]=\\
&=(e^{-(\mu_1+\mu_2)+\mu_1e^{i\xi }+\mu_2e^{-i\xi}})(e^{-(\nu_1+\nu_2)+\nu_1e^{i\xi }+\nu_2e^{-i\xi}})=\\
&=e^{-(\mu_1+\nu_1+\mu_2+\nu_2)+(\mu_1+\nu_1)e^{i\xi}+(\mu_2+\nu_2)e^{-i\xi}}\end{aligned}$$
So $Z=X+Y$ is Skellam-distributed with parameters $\mu_1+\nu_1,\mu_2+\nu_2$. This generalizes to arbitrary finite sums of independent Skellam rvs. Also, the difference of two independent Skellam-distributed rvs is Skellam distributed with parameters $\mu_1+\nu_2,\mu_2+\nu_1$.