# Does the distribution resulting from swapping variables in the Poisson distribution have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

A [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $\lambda$ for a random variable X is given by the probability distribution

$P(X=k) = \mathcal{P}_\lambda(k) = \lambda^{k}\ \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \,.$

Let this be the conditional distribution $P(X=k|\lambda)$. Then we can encounter scenarios (constant priors, not sure if this should be reconsidered in this context) where through Bayes theorem, one gets

$P(\lambda|X=k) \propto P(X=k|\lambda) = \mathcal{P}_\lambda(k)\,.$

However, this is not a Poisson distribution anymore, since *$\lambda$ is the random variable now*. **Are there any analytically known results about this distribution that arises from swapping variables in the Poisson distribution?**

Besides the usual mean and variance, I am particularly looking for the corresponding characteristic function and, if possible, composition laws for sums and differences of such variables (such as they exist for the Poisson distribution itself, see [Poisson Distribution of sum of two random independent variables $X$, $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y), [Sum of two independent Skellam distributed random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673807/sum-of-two-independent-skellam-distributed-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment9879356_4673807)).

Comment: You may be interested in the concept of [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)

Comment: @Snoop hm, interesting! So I should simply choose a different prior for convenience? Is the prior not given by the setting/my previous prior knowledge?